# Message Broadcasting using aSmack,(XMPP)

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I'm working with one live chatting application via XMPP, Used aSmack as client and configured ejabberd for server end. I'm Implement one to one chat and it's working fantastic. Now I'm trying to integrate Broadcast message to Multiple user.

I'm learn [XEP-0033](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) protocol because I know this protocol is responsible for message broadcasting and also getting full theoretically clarity on same  Basically my question is

1. I'm not getting any proper reference for integrate this protocol in my code.
2. Is aSmack is provide a predefined stanza for this protocol or May I need to make custom stanza to integrating this protocol. If yes than please suggest any reference link for same.
3. I'm also check `MultiUserChatLightManager` but this class is for Group chat but I need to first integrate Message broadcasting.
4. Is any change is required at ejabberd server side for implementing this protocol?

I'm not too much expert on XMPP.

Answer (score 1):

i had the similar problem and was solved using this

upload a broadcast plugin to your openfire server.link is [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp)
and the read me link for the plugin [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/broadcast/readme.html)

for broadcasting the message follow the pattern to set To Id 
all@[serviceName].[serverName]
where `serviceName` is `broadcast` and `serverName` is  our server name
send your xmpp message from your android client like this

```
  Message msg = new Message();
  msg.setBody(yourmessage);
  msg.setFrom(yourJid);
  msg.setTo("all@broadcast.yourservername");
  yourXmppConnection.sendStanza(msg)
```

for other alternative and high customization in broadcasting message you can go for  `XEP-0060: Publish-Subscribe` [here](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) 
and [here](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/extensions/pubsub.md) is the smack e.g

Comment: Thanks Mangesh for reply,(+1)
How we create broadcast list?Is it possible to create via client side or may request to server for create list?
if you have any code snippet from same than please send me.

Comment: above code is for android client. this line will send message to all your users   msg.setTo("all@broadcast.yourservername"); please read the readme of  the plugin given in link